# Excel VBA code to import emails into spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, email, import

I have inherited a spreadsheet which has VBA code, unfortunately the colleague has left the organisation and we need to make 3 amendments.

1. The code works on a subfolder called Procedures located in Comms stored in your personal inbox however we have moved to a team mailbox, so can anyone assist with how to change the code to address this?
2. We need to pull the senders email address currently it pulls the persons name on occasion it will identify an email but that is very limited (is it to do with the SMTP address?)
3. Once it has imported the emails can it move them to a folder called imported.

```
Sub GetFromOutlook()

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Comms").Folders("Procedures")

i = 1

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
    If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("From_date").Value Then
        Range("eMail_subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
        Range("eMail_date").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
        Range("eMail_sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
        Range("eMail_text").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
        Range("eMail_senderaddress").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderEmailAddress
        
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next OutlookMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to download all emails from Outlook, and record everything, sort of like an audit trail of emails, the script below will do the job for you.  Note:  you need to run this in Excel.

```
Option Explicit On
Const fPath As String = "C:\Users\your_path_here\" 'The path to save the messages

Sub Download_Outlook_Mail_To_Excel()
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olFolder As Object
    Dim olNS As Object
    Dim xlBook As Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
    Dim NextRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim olItem As Object
    Set xlBook = Workbooks.Add
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Sheets(1)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err() <> 0 Then
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    With xlSheet
        .Cells(1, 1) = "Sender"
        .Cells(1, 2) = "Subject"
        .Cells(1, 3) = "Date"
        '.Cells(1, 4) = "Size"
        .Cells(1, 5) = "EmailID"
        .Cells(1, 6) = "Body"
        CreateFolders fPath
        Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set olFolder = olNS.PickFolder
        For Each olItem In olFolder.Items
            NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            If olItem.Class = 43 Then
                .Cells(NextRow, 1) = olItem.Sender
                .Cells(NextRow, 2) = olItem.Subject
                .Cells(NextRow, 3) = olItem.SentOn
                '.Cells(NextRow, 4) =
                .Cells(NextRow, 5) = SaveMessage(olItem)
                '.Cells(NextRow, 6) = olItem.Body 'Are you sure?
            End If
        Next olItem
    End With
    MsgBox "Outlook Mails Extracted to Excel"
lbl_Exit:
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Function SaveMessage(olItem As Object) As String
    Dim Fname As String
    Fname = Format(olItem.ReceivedTime, "yyyymmdd") & Chr(32) &
            Format(olItem.ReceivedTime, "HH.MM") & Chr(32) & olItem.sendername & " - " & olItem.Subject
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(58) & Chr(41), "")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(58) & Chr(40), "")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(34), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(42), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(47), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(58), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(60), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(62), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(63), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(124), "-")
    SaveMessage = SaveUnique(olItem, fPath, Fname)
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
End Function

Private Function SaveUnique(oItem As Object,
                            strPath As String,
                            strFileName As String) As String
    Dim lngF As Long
    Dim lngName As Long
    lngF = 1
    lngName = Len(strFileName)
    Do While FileExists(strPath & strFileName & ".msg") = True
        strFileName = Left(strFileName, lngName) & "(" & lngF & ")"
        lngF = lngF + 1
    Loop
    oItem.SaveAs strPath & strFileName & ".msg"
    SaveUnique = strPath & strFileName & ".msg"
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
End Function

Private Sub CreateFolders(strPath As String)
    Dim strTempPath As String
    Dim iPath As Long
    Dim vPath As Variant
    vPath = Split(strPath, "\")
    strPath = vPath(0) & "\"
    For iPath = 1 To UBound(vPath)
        strPath = strPath & vPath(iPath) & "\"
        If Not FolderExists(strPath) Then MkDir strPath
    Next iPath
End Sub

Private Function FolderExists(ByVal PathName As String) As Boolean
    Dim nAttr As Long
    On Error GoTo NoFolder
    nAttr = GetAttr(PathName)
    If (nAttr And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
        FolderExists = True
    End If
NoFolder:
End Function

Private Function FileExists(filespec) As Boolean
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fso.FileExists(filespec) Then
        FileExists = True
    Else
        FileExists = False
    End If
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the code unfortunately its not about just saving it to a network drive for audit  -  The excel spreadsheet is used in conjunction with a standalone system and database.  when imported into the database it looks at the email address and identifies have we had that customer before and then links to that account and the next layer of staff deal with the query using a workflow queue .

Comment: So, are you all set now, or do you still need help with this?

Comment: Hi Ash no I still need some assistance

Comment: So, what do you need?